# How do I use the drive I just mapped on net use? (C++)

Tags: c++, dictionary, networking, drive

I'm writing code on C++ that will map to the nearest available drive using "net use * \server...etc" and afterwards I want to open a file on it.

Is there a command that will let me interact with this new drive without needing to know on which drive it was mapped beforehand? (Usually it will be drive Z:, but not always!)

Clearer example:

```
 system("net use * \\server\folder\ p455word /user:server\user /p:no")

(output: "Server succesfully mapped to drive Z:")
```

Then I would normally try to open the file:

```
system("Z:\\folder\mydoc.docx")
```

My question is on how to do this:

```
system("*\\\folder\mydoc.docx")
```

With * being whatever the drive the computer chose to map to, or if there's a workaround to this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for some `net use`-specific magic here, you're going to be disappointed. Your program simply passes a text string to the Windows shell, and has no knowledge or information about the command you've performed. It certainly can't pull out status information about the result of that call, beyond reading the command's text output.

Fortunately, the text output is all you need — your quote shows that the assigned drive letter is right there. You just need to pull it out, then construct the subsequent `system` calls dynamically by building up a string from the now-known drive letter, and the fixed part of your path.

`system` is not really designed for any of this, though. [Here's how to execute a command and retrieve its output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/478898/560648). Extracting the drive letter from the string `"Server succesfully mapped to drive Z:"` would also be a separate question. In general, when you have a problem, break it down into component parts; then you'll be able to "look it up" with success.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! However, given how insanely complicated it turned out to be, I found a workaround as suggested in the comments. If anyone has this same problem, you can use its UNC path "\\server\folder" to connect to it without prompting for password regardless of where the drive was mapped.

i.e: 

net use * \\kratos\folder passw0rd /user:kratos\zeus /p:no

can then be accesed simply as:
explorer \\kratos\folder

Regardless if it was mapped on Q: A: or Z: :)

Comment: @J.Doe: That has nothing to do with C++ and is thus out of scope of the question.